# How to deal with users clicking on C# console application window which causes Console.WriteLine to hang

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

When you run a C# console application and click on the console window, the executing thread hangs on any lines which write to the console, and only resumes when you press a key. I want to know what the best practice is for dealing with this.

Possible solutions that I can think of:

1. It's not an issue. If the user clicks the console window, that is their fault. It's standard and accepted behavior for C# console applications to do this.
2. Make another thread just for writing to console. Sort of like how an application with a UI should have a separate UI thread.
3. Use some `Console`/`TextWriter` method which I don't know about that writes to console without blocking the execution thread. I thought that `Console.Out.WriteLineAsync` was what I wanted but it hangs just like `Console.WriteLine` does.

Comment: Answer 1 is correct. Console terminal behaviour is not something you need to worry about. I would personally recommend not try to change the default experience.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for. Besides, I expect most users to install this application as a Windows service, so in my case it will very rarely be an issue.

Comment: The behavior you take as _standard_ is controlled by the Console window property "Quick EditMode" (Right-Click TitleBar->Properities->Options).  The System.Console does not expose the ability to alter that property.  You would need to use the API [SetConsoleMode function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) using the input handle.